# How to use ngx-translate in a library

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I have made a library, let's call it `user_setting`, in my app, which is responsible for showing users' data.

The problem is with `translation`. I have defined a `Setting` item in my navigation menu, which when a user opens it, a page with two buttons, i.e., `device_setting` and `user_setting` is shown. When the user clicks the `user_setting`, the library is opened and labels are translated in the library, but when the user returns back to the app, the labels in the app are not any more translated!

Interestingly, if I open the library directly from the main navigation menu (by adding `user setting` in the main navigation), the translation works both in the library and also in the app.

In other words, if the library is opened as an item in navigation menu, translation works perfectly in both the library and the app. But if the library is opened from inside a page in the app, then the app translation is not working unless I close and reopen the app.

Here is the user_setting.module.ts:

```
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { UserSettingComponent } from './user-setting.component';
import { UserSettingRoutingModule } from './user-setting-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    UserSettingRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [UserSettingComponent]
})
export class UserSettingModule {}
```

Here is the user-setting.component.ts:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
export class UserSettingComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor( private translate: TranslateService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init(this.translate); // adding this line, the translation in the app wont work, removing it the translatin in the library wont work 
    this.translate.use('en');
  }

  init(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setTranslation('en', this.en_data);    
  }
}
```

Does any one know what is the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should use: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

> user-setting.module.ts

```
@NgModule()
export class UserSettingModule {
  static forRoot(config: {translateService: TranslateService}): ModuleWithProviders<UserSettingModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: UserSettingModule,
      declarations: [UserSettingComponent],
      exports: [UserSettingComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: 'TRANSLATE_SERVICE', useValue: config.traslateService}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    UserSettingRoutingModule,
    UserSettingModule.forRoot({ translateService: TranslateService })
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> user-setting.component.ts

```
export class UserSettingComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('TRANSLATE_SERVICE') translateService: TranslateService) {}
}
```

Comment: I applied the above correction, but then, in the app, I got a lot of errors indicating `If '' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module` . To fix these errors, I removed `imports: [..., UserSettingModule.forRoot({ translateService: TranslateService })]`. But now when starting the app, its labels are not translated. Also `user_setting`, which is opened as a modal, is not opening at all from inside the setting page!

Comment: maybe you forgot to add declarations & exports for forRoot method?

Comment: If I move `declarations: [UserSettingComponent],` and `exports: UserSettingComponent],` from `@NgModule()` to `export class UserSettingModule` then I get `If '' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.` errors in my lib.

Comment: Well I could solve the problem, but in a totally different way. I was so sure that something in the lib is wrong but the problem was in **how I had opened the lib**! In fact, when I was opening the lib from inside the `Setting` page, I was using a modal! But when I was opening it from the navigation menu, I was using routerLink! So I changed the modal to routerLink and now it is working.